# Binding to an observableCollection<string> listview

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, binding, observablecollection

If i have a ListView (called "MainList") and want to bind to elements in a collection, how is this done.

Main.Items.Add(new ObserableCollection() { "hello", "world" }

then

Why doesnt this work? Ive tried loads of other combinations of bindings as well....

Thanks

U.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you haven't tried is this:

```
Main.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<string> { "hello", "world" };
```

In your own code you actually added the whole collection as an item in a `ListView`. Surely that was not your real intention.